# How to find elements with blank html tags in selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver, firebug

This is what firebug displays when used inspect element on a radio button

```
<div class="content-inner">
    <div =" " =" " =" " =" " =" " =" " =" " =" " =" " =" " =" " =" " =" ">



    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's... bizarre. Are you *sure* you're inspecting a radio button? Do you perhaps have a link to the page you're inspecting?

Comment: Well it is an internal app so cannot provide a link to it. But it is quite bizarre do not how to get that element!!

Comment: In the case of an internal app, you should break your issue down to a simple test case, which you can publish here. From the code you posted it looks like your app is producing invalid output, because the attributes don't have names. To confirm that you should inspect the element using a different devtool than Firebug. Also ensure that the radio button - i.e. `<input type="radio" ... />` is not covered by the `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Most DOM implementations (and possibly the spec, I haven't checked) are very tolerant about the data that they let you add. It wouldn't surprise me in the slightest if the DOM allows you to create an attribute with no name, or a name that consists of a zero-length string. I would suggest that Firebug is faithfully displaying the junk that your application has created in the DOM.